# Optimize mysql subquery containing self-join to reduce CPU Usage

Tags: mysql, self-join

I understand that mysql query involving self-join table might lead to slow query and/or CPU spike, but have been struggling to come up with ways to improve it.

```
CREATE TABLE `tool` (
  `tool_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `provider` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tool_id`),
)

CREATE TABLE `edata` (
  `e_data_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `tool_id` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_e_data_id` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`e_data_id`),
  KEY `e_ref_e_data__06a0c1a7_fk` (`ref_e_data_id`),
  KEY `edata_tool_id_61d6bb9b` (`tool_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `e_tool_id_61d6bb9b` FOREIGN KEY (`tool_id`) REFERENCES `tool` (`tool_id`),
)
```

here is the query in question

```
mutdata
LEFT JOIN (SELECT e1.edata_id as m_id, a1.provider as m_cp from edata e1 INNER JOIN tool a1 on e1.tool_id=a1.tool_id WHERE a1.deleted=0) as mapping 
on mutdata.ref_e_data_id=mapping.m_id or mutdata.e_data_id=map.m_id
```

in short, first the subquery is constructed as a lookup table like a dictionary or map, then mutdata tries to use the lookup table to determine the corresponding provider (this query is part of even larger query). Is there a way to optimize this part?

Comment: Left joins with subqueries are troublesome, because you need an index in the right side table. And though MySQL sometimes returns a temporary table with an index from the subquery, you kind of have no control if that index will be useful for your join. One workaround is to use an inner join instead and simulate the left join in application code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: What's the reason for `CHAR(32)` instead of `INT`?

Answer (score 0):

These indexes may help:

```
mutdata:  INDEX(ref_e_data_id,  e_data_id)
map:  INDEX(m_id)
e1:  INDEX(tool_id,  edata_id)
a1:  INDEX(deleted, tool_id,  provider)
```

Try not to use the construct `JOIN ( SELECT ... )`; instead try to bump that up a level.

Do you really need `LEFT` in either place?

`OR` is terrible for performance.  Sometimes it is practical to use two `SELECT` connected by `UNION DISTINCT` as a workaround.  That way, each `SELECT` may be able to take advantage of a different index.

Where is `map` in the query?